# putting the title in the header for an article

Tags: formatting, header-footer, titles

For various reasons, I need to put my name and title in the header of a LaTeX document. The reason is I have a page limit and need the extra space which is taken up by \maketitle.   Does anyone know how to do this? For reference, I am using the standard amsart document class.

What I have tried so far is to use the package fancyhdr and then writing

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight=14pt

\fancyhf{}

\lhead{name}
\rhead{title}
```

in the preamble, but I cannot get the header to appear on the first page (the desired header appears on subsequent pages). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including `\thispagestyle{fancy}` adds the title to the first page:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `lipsum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used just to provide dummy text. It is not needed in your document.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight=14pt

\fancyhf{}

\lhead{name}
\rhead{title}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! May I ask what the purpose of \thispagestyle{fancy} is?

Comment: That'll teach me _not_ to guess at solutions!! :-)  I don't know for sure, but would guess (opps, here I go again) that the page style is set to `plain` initially so that the header/footer does not show up on the title page (which is normally the desired behavior).

Comment: Thank you. But I found my page numbers are correspondingly missed!

Comment: @Comeseeconquer: I am not sure if you are asking a question. If so, please post a new question. If this solution worked for you then you should give feedback clicking the 'up' arrow you can see above each answer's score.