# Disable exceptional behavior of the first page in letter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, letters

I use the following code for my letter:

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{letter}

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\newcommand{\DocumentTitle}{Motivation Letter}
\newcommand{\Author}{Johm Smith}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\fancyhead[L]{\DocumentTitle \\ \Author}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\DocumentTitle \\ \Author}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{ }

\signature{\Author}

\opening{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closing{Respectfully,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

But there is no these header and footer on the first page. How to change this behavior?

Comment: Try `\thispagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Putting the title in the header for an article](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81596/putting-the-title-in-the-header-for-an-article/).

Comment: @Peter Grill Where I must put this.

Comment: You would normally add it to the preamble, but your code seems to work fine with the `letter` class.  So, while code snippets are useful in explanations, I recommend you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `letter` document class, `\opening` issues `\thispagestyle{firstpage}`, where `\ps@firstpage` is defined in `letter.cls` for the first page of a letter. To apply the same header/footer to this page, you can `\let` the `firstpage` style to be `fancy`, using

```
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@fancy
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{letter}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\newcommand{\DocumentTitle}{Motivation Letter}
\newcommand{\Author}{Johm Smith}

%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\fancyhead[L]{\DocumentTitle \\ \Author}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\DocumentTitle \\ \Author}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{ }
\signature{\Author}

\opening{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closing{Respectfully,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I commented out the line `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` in my example code, since I don't have this font in my system.